# GCM push notifications not working in Google TV

Tags: google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging, google-tv

[image: An application with google play services shows this error on Google TV]

How to push notifications to an android Google TV?
My application works perfectly fine on my mobile but not on Google TV.
It requires Google play services on Google TV which is not available in its play store.

We are trying to run an app on Google TV box from Sony running Android 3.2

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for reading the post.

Comment: which model of google tv is that?

Comment: Sony n5z-gt1 running Android 3.2

Answer (score 0):

i dont know much about GCM.but please make sure that you are running google APIs in the target device

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing play services from here ?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en